# How to manipulate IBOutlet UIImageView objects in series using For Loop

Tags: ios7, xcode6

# of Images are placed in a View using Storyboard.
I want to manipulate them programmatically using a For loop. But couldn't find how to?

Currently i am using the following code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img_level2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img_level3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img_level4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img_level5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img_level6;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img_level7;
...
...
...
_img_level2.image = [_img_level2.image convertToGrayscale];
_img_level3.image = [_img_level3.image convertToGrayscale];
_img_level4.image = [_img_level4.image convertToGrayscale];
_img_level5.image = [_img_level5.image convertToGrayscale];
_img_level6.image = [_img_level6.image convertToGrayscale];
_img_level7.image = [_img_level7.image convertToGrayscale];
```

Now instead of writing them line by line i want to use a for loop. Because this procedure might be called multiple times for sizing and positioning.

Please advice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having each of the buttons as its own UIButton property, you can define an outlet collection, which is essentially an array that you'll be able to treat exactly as you want (for example, loop over all of its items).

How do you do that? Simple:

In your code, replace all of the `IBOutlet UIImageView...` lines with:

```
IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSMutableArray *imgLevels;
```

On InterfaceBuilder, give each of your UIImageViews a different tag that will match its index in the IBOutletCollection.

And, finally, when you connect the objects on your .xib or storyboard file, you'll notice it will appear on the **Referencing Outlet Collections** section instead of the **Referencing Outlets** as you're used to.

Now you have an array that you can use to loop over your IBOutlets exactly as you would loop a "regular" NSArray. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you, seems like a solid approach, but out of curiosity, how would it would be possible to achieve this without using IBOutletCollection? Because let's suppose if we are dynamically creating UIImage objects, then there would be no IBOutletCollection?

Comment: That would be even easier. You will just manually create the array and whenever you dynamically create the UIImageView, you add it to the array.

Comment: Create all of the images in a loop like this: UIImageView *curImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame]; and then add the actual image to the image view, add the image view to the screen like this [self.view addSubview:curImg]; and add the image view to your array like this [imgLevels addObject:curImg]; Then, you have the same array as the collection I referenced in my original answer.